# How to install Rails using RVM in steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, linux-mint

I used

```
\curl -v -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

to install Rails, but it fails at different points (intermittent network failure).

How do I install Rails in little bits using RVM that's equivalent to running the above command:

```
ruby-2.2.1 -
#compiling...............................................................................
ruby-2.2.1 - #installing............................ ruby-2.2.1 -
#making binaries executable.. ruby-2.2.1 - #downloading rubygems-2.4.8   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time 
Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100  437k  100  437k    0     0   126k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03
--:--:--  126k No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration. ruby-2.2.1 - #extracting rubygems-2.4.8....
ruby-2.2.1 - #removing old rubygems......... ruby-2.2.1 - #installing
rubygems-2.4.8...................... ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset created
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global ruby-2.2.1 - #importing gemset
/home/user/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems...............................................
ruby-2.2.1 - #generating global wrappers........ ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset
created /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 ruby-2.2.1 - #importing
gemsetfile /home/user/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem
list ruby-2.2.1 - #generating default wrappers........ ruby-2.2.1 -
#adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake). Install of ruby-2.2.1 - #complete  Ruby was built without documentation, to build
it run: rvm docs generate-ri Creating alias default for ruby-2.2.1...
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%) Successfully installed
thread_safe-0.3.5 Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%) Successfully
installed tzinfo-1.2.2 Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%) Successfully
installed i18n-0.7.0 Fetching: activesupport-4.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.4 Fetching:
rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3.gem (100%) Successfully installed
rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3 Fetching: mini_portile-0.6.2.gem
(100%) Successfully installed mini_portile-0.6.2 Fetching:
nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem (100%) Building native extensions.  This could
take a while... Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.6.2 Fetching:
rails-dom-testing-1.0.7.gem (100%) Successfully installed
rails-dom-testing-1.0.7 Fetching: loofah-2.0.3.gem (100%) Successfully
installed loofah-2.0.3 Fetching: rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2 Fetching:
erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%) Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0 Fetching:
builder-3.2.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: actionview-4.2.4.gem (100%) Successfully installed
actionview-4.2.4 Fetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%) Successfully
installed rack-1.6.4 ERROR:  While executing gem ...
(OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A
```

Comment: It's really important to read [the documentation for installing RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) before you start so you understand what it's doing. Actually, it's pretty important to read the installation docs for doing any install, software, hardware or garage doors. Rails is a multipart system, but it's easy to install RVM, a Ruby, then Rails in separate steps. The RVM documentation shows how to do the first two and the Rails documentation shows how to do the last.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use my shell script to install all necessary files for rails development https://github.com/navinspm/easy_rails